# AWS APIG Lambda Proxy Custom Headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, http-headers, aws-api-gateway, content-type

I am fairly new to serverless and so my experience with AWS Lambda is limited to the past few months. So far I love it. The only problem I have right now is that I can't seem to send custom headers through a Lambda Proxy integration on API Gateway. When my function code is reached, my "Authorization" header is in tact. Unfortunately, I cannot retrieve the "Content-Type" header or any custom headers I might add. I've been able to get away without needing them so far but I'm working on a multipart/form-data request and need that good good boundary from the Content-Type header. What's weirder is that when I make requests using Postman, everything is golden. Anywhere else, the headers go missing. If anyone has any information on why this super weird thing is ruining my days and nights, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You *might* find that it's been moved under `x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Type`.  Check that?  Simplest test of course is to write a Lambda function that returns its input, stringified, as the response body.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the answer by following Michael's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) suggestion which should have been obvious to me. Just return the whole input and check what headers I get. What I found was that "Content-Type" was being changed to "content-type" and that case sensitivity caused the problem. I am still unsure how postman requests were able to preserve the upper case convention when no other request did but it works now.

Comment: Postman would know that headers are case-insensitive and will know what to do with it. But programming languages (at least the ones used for AWS Lambda), would simply see an object or a dictionary with the `content-type` key.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem except I'm not receiving the Content-Type header at all, not even with lowercase. Any other custom headers are being received, but not Content-Type

Comment: @ffleandro Just a hunch because I don't know anything about your system but are you trying to run a multipart/form-data request through postman to your lambda? I found that when I do that, postman includes the Content-Type header on the first request but subsequent requests don't send the content type. I don't know why. Anyway, if you remove your form values and put them back in, postman sets the Content-Type back in.

Comment: No I'm calling the api manually using a curl command and setting the header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`